# Error message "date: Argument list too long" bash

Tags: bash

So, everything works fine in the code, except for one tiny little thing.

This part:

```
if [ "$LIMITHOURS" -gt "0" -a "$LIMITHOURS" -lt "24" ]; then
    x=$(($LIMITHOURS*60*60))
fi
SDATE=$( echo "01/jan/2003:11:00:06 +0100"| sed 's/[/]/ /g' |sed 's/:/ /')
EDATE=$(date --date "$SDATE - $x seconds" +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S")

#echo "$SDATE"
#echo "$EDATE"


while read LINE; do
CDATE=$( awk '{print $4}'| sed 's/[[]//' | sed 's/[/]//g' |sed 's/://g' ) 
DATE=$(date --date "$CDATE" +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S")

#echo "$CDATE"
done < "$FILENAME"
```

When I try to run the script, I get the error message "date: Argument list too long
" and I know that the problem is in the while loop, with:

> DATE=$(date --date "$CDATE" +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S")

Anyone who know any solution for this? I want the date format in ddmmYYYYHHMMSS, eg. 23102002120022

You can find rest of the script here: http://pastebin.com/PMk2QDre

Comment: @TomFenech, does it matter? argv+envp size limit isn't exactly a version-specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
while read LINE; do
CDATE=$( awk '{print $4}'| sed 's/[[]//' | sed 's/[/]//g' |sed 's/://g' ) 
DATE=$(date --date "$CDATE" +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S")

#echo "$CDATE"
done < "$FILENAME"
```

will read one line from `$FILENAME` into the variable `LINE`, but then the first call to `awk` is reading the rest of the lines. The resulting `CDATE` value is probably too large to fit in a single command line, never mind it containing too many dates. You probably wanted

```
echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $4}' | ...
```

A simpler way to strip the undesirable characters from `LINE`, however, is

```
CDATE=${LINE//[\/[:]}
```